# Creating a Project programmatially in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have tried by using the GCP console dashboard to create the project and I want to **programmatically** create the **projects** by using Google supported **APIs** to manage projects. Then I want to perform Google Big Query operations by using **Big Query Client** libraries for the .NET project.

Is there any way to create Google Cloud Platform "Projects" by using Google Cloud API service?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable [`cloud resource manager`](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager) and,create project using resource manager.refer the documentation

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `gcloud` command or REST API. You need to have a user (or service account) which has permissions to create the GCP Project.

Here is one of the REST API example

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/
Authorization: *************
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "projectId": "project-123",
    "name": "project name"
}
```

You can find more examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects).

Hope this helps.